# How did they do this beauty setup? What lights and focal length? Help me recreate this

Tags: lighting, focal-length

From examination the lighting source appears to be 2 fluorescent panels and a light ring. How many lux/lumens/watts is he using?

What's the focal length for the field of view is he using? (35mm equivalent)

How would I go about recreating that look and soft skin?

[image]

Edit** here's some more pictures of the panel in question
Can anyone identify what these are?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Codi, Welcome to Photography StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience here.

Comment: There is no evidence of a light ring [sic] (ring-light) according to the appearance of the catchlights reflected in the subject's eyes. There is only evidence of two lights to either side of the subject.

Comment: This kind of question is great for the site, but the title isn't very descriptive — can you edit it to be more specific to this particular image?

Comment: I went ahead and changed the title. My goal is to recreate the soft look that he achieved in this

Comment: But what is *this*? Imagine how many completely different images could have this same title.

Comment: Okay correction again

Comment: "recreating... soft skin" – The lens focal length wouldn't cause "soft skin". The perspective looks like the camera is close to the model's face, maybe 28-35mm (full frame).

Comment: If you have a high-res image, you might be able to see the camera reflected in her eyes.

Comment: Is it me ( and it frequently is ) or is this photo just not good, ( badly focused. )

Comment: @Alaska Man It looks like its actually a video still.

Answer (score 1):

The lighting looks like a copy of the classic "Kino Flo 4' 4-bank" [except it's got 5 tubes].
Mainly used for video, as it is constant lighting, is it essentially a set of fluorescent tubes fixed to a board, wrapped in soft material [reflective or black] surrounded by a wire frame. This lets the operator open or close like barn doors to permit more or less light through. That particular version has a white interior, to further diffuse the light when opened.

Original Kino Flo...

[image]

<sup>Pic: [Adorama](https://www.adorama.com/kfcfx484.html)</sup>

You don't see them on set so much these days as they've mainly been replaced by LED versions.

[image]

<sup>Pic: [BHPhoto](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1340323-REG/kino_flo_cfx_f21_freestyle_21_led_fixture.html)</sup>

The major downside of using these so close to your model is they're really bright & blinding. If they're adjustable, you can turn them down, but by the time you're reaching comfortable for the model, you're getting too dim for the photographer.
Better would be softboxes with speedlights [flash]

[image]

<sup>Pic & tutorial - [ImprovePhototography](https://improvephotography.com/11662/softbox/)</sup>

You can get these with modelling lights, bright enough that you can see your setup, dim enough to not blind the model.

Setting these lights close to the model & at approx 45° each side will flatten the light a lot - removing most facial shadows. 
I see no hint of a ring light in her eyes, just those two.

As to which lens - I'm not sure; something quite wide, maybe 18-24mm. Personally I think it's far too wide for 'fashion' photography, it looks very much like a selfie - big nose, little ears.
The depth of field is distracting, though it's not quite sharp even at the eyes, it doesn't get soft enough to the background. The lighting reflecting in the TV should have been spotted earlier & corrected.

I wouldn't be surprised if it was taken on a phone.

The white balance looks like it's been corrected afterwards, to emphasise pink/purple, compared to the setup shots.